# Visiting the UK on a Child visitor visa after turning 18

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for a UK visa to travel with my parents within a period of time, but that trip did not work out and I have a visa stating accompanied. If I need to travel to the UK without my parents after I have turned 18 will that be a problem?

Comment: Visa conditions apply.  If you reach the age of 18 and want to travel on your own, you will need to apply for a new visa.

Answer (score 2):

Four months with no answer, hmmmm....

From comments...

[image]

What this means is that child visitor visa does not 'automatically' switch to a standard visitor just because the person turned 18. If you continue to use the visa (which is ok), you need to abide the terms and conditions, like accompanied by a parent or chaperone. Hopefully the carrier will prevent you from boarding if they see you are in breach.

If you want to travel on your own, you can apply for a standard visitor visa and explain that you are living an independent life and need a visa commensurate with your lifestyle.